# update using custom query and rawQuery or execSQL not working

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-update

I'm using a personal query to update values ​​in a table, in this case to increase the value of certain columns.
For example, would I do something like:

```
UPDATE statistica SET 1PF = 1PF + ? WHERE id_statistica = ?;
```

My code is as follows:

```
String sql = "UPDATE " + StatisticaTable.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + StatisticaTable._1PF + " = " + StatisticaTable._1PF + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable._1PN + " = " + StatisticaTable._1PN + " + ?, " + 
                                                                    StatisticaTable._2PF + " = " + StatisticaTable._2PF + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable._2PN + " = " + StatisticaTable._2PN + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable._3PF + " = " + StatisticaTable._3PF + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable._3PN + " = " + StatisticaTable._3PN + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable.RD + " = " + StatisticaTable.RD + " + ?, " + StatisticaTable.RO + " = " + StatisticaTable.RO + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable.PR + " = " + StatisticaTable.PR + " + ?, " + StatisticaTable.AS + " = " + StatisticaTable.AS + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable.BK + " = " + StatisticaTable.BK + " + ?, " + StatisticaTable.FS + " = " + StatisticaTable.FS + " + ?, " +
                                                                    StatisticaTable.PP + " = " + StatisticaTable.PP + " + ?, " + StatisticaTable.FP + " = " + StatisticaTable.FP + " + ? " +
                                                                    "WHERE " + GiocatoreTable.ID_GIOCATORE + "= ? AND + " + StatisticaTable.ID_PARTITA + "= ?;";

    String[] parameter = new String[] {String.valueOf(values.get1pf()), String.valueOf(values.get1pn()), String.valueOf(values.get2pf()), String.valueOf(values.get2pn()), 
                                       String.valueOf(values.get3pf()), String.valueOf(values.get3pn()), String.valueOf(values.getRD()), String.valueOf(values.getRO()), String.valueOf(values.getPR()), 
                                       String.valueOf(values.getAS()), String.valueOf(values.getBK()), String.valueOf(values.getFS()), 
                                       String.valueOf(values.getPP()), String.valueOf(values.getFP()), String.valueOf(values.getIDGiocatore()), String.valueOf(values.getIDPartita())};

_dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql, parameter);
```

Essentially the code is this... But does not update anything (either using both execSQL rawQuery) in spite of the parameters are passed correctly and the sql string is formed in the right way ...
I do not understand what is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't get any SQL Exception then perhaps you should focus on the WHERE statment.

```
"WHERE " + GiocatoreTable.ID_GIOCATORE + "= ? AND + " + StatisticaTable.ID_PARTITA + "= ?;";
```

SQLite can be a little tricky sometimes since it only use five basic datatypes.
I've noticed that WHERE statements can fail if the stored database value and
the search parameter are of different types. Try to convert the ID_GIOCATORE parameter
and the ID_PARTITA parameter into the native type used in the database.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thank you, you've been a help to understand how to change the query.
I solved by changing the parameters passed (in the database are all of type NUMERIC) from the type String[] to type Object[].
Now the query works fine!